# Does a DC power supply 24V 6A that functions as a motor for a standing desk produce radiation that might be harmful?

Tags: power-supply, radiation

Just curious to know if there's any radiation coming from it that can be harmful if we stay close.

Thanks.

Comment: [No.](https://www.who.int/news-room/questions-and-answers/item/radiation-electromagnetic-fields)

Comment: strap on that tin foil hat!

Answer (score 2):

There are no standard commercial 24V power supplies that put out harmful radiation of any kind. Some cheaper ones may produce a bit of radio interference which, for example, you might pick up if you brought your mobile phone or a radio close enough, but this isn't harmful, just possibly annoying.

Obviously if you build a power supply to your own design nothing can be said, but you'd have to be particularly clever or stupid to achieve any dangerous radiation and I can't think of how you would do it. You need specialised components that have no place in in a PSU.

Comment: Your first sentence needs correcting.

Comment: @HandyHowie What do you think it should say?

Comment: My mistake.  I read it several times and it didn’t seem to make sense.  Reading it again later, it now makes sense.  I read the first ‘No’ as if you were answering no, which made the rest of the sentence appear to contradict it.  Sorry.

Comment: @HandyHowie No problem, thanks for pointing out that the wording wasn't that good. I've updated it to be clearer - I hope.